# What is the "rule of 70" or "rule of 72" with regards to investment, and how do I apply it?

Tags: investing, interest-rate, calculation, financial-literacy, rate-of-return

What is the "rule of 72" (sometimes called the "rule of 70") with regards to investment, and how do I apply it?

Answer (score 14):

The [Rule of 72](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72) is a rough guide for calculating how long it would take to double your investment through compound interest, given a fixed yearly rate of return.

It means that the time taken (in years) to double your investment value is approximately equal to:

```
 72 / return of investment (%) per year.
```

Example: Assuming you have invested an amount, X, in an investment returning 6% per year, and you reinvest all the returns from the investment. Then, using the Rule of 72, the time taken to double your investment value to 2X would be approximately `72 / 6 = 12 years`.

It could also be used to calculate how long it takes for **inflation to reduce the value of your money by half** .

The Rule of 72 demonstrates the principle behind why it's never too soon to start investing – it could be the difference between $2 million and $4 million.

Answer (score 5):

Here another example on how to apply it:

If I invest 1$ at 5% for 30 years, what will I have at the end?

5% means we double every 72/5 years, so about every 14 years. Thus, in 30 years, I double it a bit more than twice, so I expect to have a bit more than $1 x 2 x 2 = $4.

If you want to be more precise, you could figure that we double twice in about 28 years, then have 2 years left, with every year giving 5%, so we slap 2*5% or 10% on top of the $4, to get $4.40.

If you want to be really precise, you get a calculator and compute

- 1.05^30 = 4.32 for annual compounding, or
- exp(0.05*30) = 4.48 for continuous compounding

and we see that the rule performs quite well :-)

Comment: +1 - Welcome to Money.SE. Nice explanation and example of how close the estimate is to the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, JoeTaxpayer. I must say, this is addictive :-)

Answer (score 3):

With continuous compounding at a rate that yields 100x% per annum, in y years
(y need not be an integer) an investment has increased by the factor (1 + x)^y.
For any given x value, this factor has value 2 exactly when y years have elapsed
where (1 + x)^y = 2, which, upon taking natural logarithms and remembering
that log(a^b) = b*log(a), gives

y = ln(2)/ln(1 + x) = 0.693/ln(1 + x)

Here, ln denotes the natural logarithm, and ln(2) happents to have
value 0.693...  Now, to a *first-order approximation,* ln(1 + x) 
equals x (actually a little bit less) when x is small, 
and so an investment yielding 100x% per annum should double
approximately 69.3/x years.  But if we take the "little bit
less" into account, 70/x or even 72/x yields a closer
approximation.

Examples:

- At 5% annual yield, an investment will double in
  a little over 14.2 years.  The 70/x and 72/x formulas
  give 14 and 14.4 years as the answer.
- At 2% annual yield, an investment will double in
  a little over 35 years.  The 70/x and 72/x formulas
  give 35 and 36 years as the answer.
- At 0.1% annual yield (which I think what my bank is
  paying on my checking account), I will have twice as
  much money in 693.5 years -- too long to wait -- but
  the 69.3/x formula is looking pretty good as compared
  to the 70/x and 72/x formulas.  Thus, as might be expected,
  that 69.3 is working better for *small* x.
- At 10% annual yield, the investment doubles in 72.7
  years instead of the 70 or 72 years estimated with the
  rule of 70 or rule of 72.
- At 100% annual yield, the investment doubles in 1 year
  which is a lot longer than the 0.7 or 0.72 years estimated
  by the rule of 70 or 72.

> In summary, the rule of 70 or 72 works well for annual
>   yields in the typical range of a few percentage points
>   but not that well for trivial yields (rule of 69.3 is better)
>   or the pie-in-the-sky yields that beginning investors plan on
>   getting so as to retire by age 35.

Comment: Just a small clarification: The growth factor is (1+x)^y with **annual** compounding. With continuous compounding, it would be exp(x*y), leading to a doubling time of y = ln(2)/x exactly. (Thus the observation that for continuous compounding, the "rule of 70" is closer, while for annual compounding with typical rates the "rule of 72" tends to be closer).